# Return Map from hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to create a Map object from the HQL

Here is my code

I am facing the exception :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

```
List<Map<Long, Long>> test = new ArrayList<Map<Long, Long>>();
try {
    String HQL_QUERY = "select new map(hp.col1, hp.col2) from HP hp where hp.col1 in (:id)";
    test = getSession().createQuery(HQL_QUERY).setParameter("id", id).list();
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

No idea where i am making mistake

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made one mistake

instead of parameter i need to use parameterlist.

Here is the code :

```
 List<Map<Long, Long>> test = new ArrayList<Map<Long, Long>>();
try {
    String HQL_QUERY = "select new map(hp.col1, hp.col2) from HP hp where hp.col1 in (:id)";
    test = getSession().createQuery(HQL_QUERY).setParameter("id", id).list();
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

HQL work like that :

```
List<MyObject> test = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    String HQL_QUERY = "select new map(hp.col1, hp.col2) from HP hp where hp.col1 in (:id)";
    test = getSession().createQuery(HQL_QUERY).setParameter("id", id).getResultlist();
}
```

so you should to chnage your Type of your attribute and after you can make some code to convert your List to a Map

Answer (score 0):

`hp.col1` or `hp.col1` is returning `java.util.ArrayList` and it should be `Long`. Change it type in entity class.

or

Change test type:
`List<Map<List, Long>> test = new ArrayList<Map<List, Long>>();`

Comment: i tried this List<Map<List, Long>> test = new ArrayList<Map<List, Long>>();  ... it is not working